# How to generate kernel crash dumps?

Tags: linux, rhel, crash

I have X running on terminal 1 and terminal 2 on my RHEL 6.4 system. If i randomly switch between tty1 and tty2, the system crashes. I need to generate crash dump file to analyze the issue. How can I generate crash dump file?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a core dump file, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a core dump file generated you need to setup your environment so that the following Bash configuration is set:

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
```

You can add this to your `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`.